# Add an unique index to an array type field in embed documents of MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, indexing

First, add an unique index to field `'items.barcode'`.

```
db.clothes.createIndex({'items.barcode': 1}, {unique: 1});
```

Then, insert some documents to the `clothes` table.

```
db.clothes1.remove({});
db.clothes.insert([
    { // success
        _id: '1',
        items: [
            {barcode: ['122', '122']},
            {barcode: ['122', '124']}
        ]
    },
    { // success
        _id: '2',
        items: [
            {barcode: ['222', '223']},
            {barcode: ['224', '225']}
        ]
    },
    { // failed
        _id: '3',
        items: [
            {barcode: ['122', '323']},
            {barcode: ['324', '325']}
        ]
    }
]);
```

Now we can see the 3rd document is inserted failed, cause the error:

> 'E11000 duplicate key error index: duolayimeng.clothes1.$items.barcode_1 dup key: { : "122" }'

But in the two embed documents of the 1st document, there are 3 elements of `'barcode'` field are `'122'`.

---

I'm puzzled about this situation. How MongoDB decides an array type field in embed documents, like `'items.barcode'`, is unique or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because, an index is unique across a **collection** of documents.

The subdocuments are not really documents, a document is forced to have a unique field, a subdocument can not be force to be unique inside a document.

Document with id 3 is failing because other document already exists having the same unique key.

Documents with id 1 is inserting OK because there is no other document with the same unique field.

When you want to achieve uniqueness inside a document, you must implement that in the client side or modify schema and add your values inside a set using [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/)

Answer (score 0):

> The unique index permits the insertion of the following document into
>   the collection if no other document in the collection has the a.b
>   value of 5:

```
db.collection.insert( { a: [ { b: 5 }, { b: 5 } ] } )
```

Here is the [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/core/index-unique/#unique-constraint-across-separate-documents)